# heroku postgres copy - "! App not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, taps

Trying to copy a production db with:

```
heroku db:pull postgres://postgres:@localhost/prod_20120717 \
--app my_app --confirm my_app
```

but I get:

```
$ heroku db:pull postgres://postgres:@localhost/prod_20120717 --app my_app \
--confirm my_app
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://postgres:@localhost/prod_20120717' \
will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
 !    App not found.
```

Comment: Just a stupid question : Is your application exist?

Comment: yes and other developers work with it.

Comment: However `heroku apps` returns 'You have no apps'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heroku is probably misconfigured. Try to do this `heroku login` and redo your login.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, please use pgbackups, not pg:pull. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups